# .animation modifier shifts view upwards in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

If you add the .animation modifier to any view it shifts the content upwards. Did anyone notice this before? It seems to be a bug in SwiftUI.

```
struct TestBlinking: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("1) Hello, World!")
                .animation(.easeInOut)
            
            Text("2) Hello, World!")
            Text("3) Hello, World!")
            Text("4) Hello, World!")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example showing Shift]

Xcode 12.4
Big Sur 11.2.3
Compiling for MacOS using Catalyst.
Problem only seems to be in Preview.

Comment: It could be a bug, but it can be fixed with us, do have still problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use explicit spacing (because by default it is different for different view pairs by design)

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {                // << here !!
        Text("1) Hello, World!")
            .animation(.easeInOut)
        
        Text("2) Hello, World!")
        Text("3) Hello, World!")
        Text("4) Hello, World!")
    }
}
```